# axios promise value returns undefined in Chrome console and a string in Firefox console

Tags: javascript, axios

when the following is executed the "console.log"  it returns nothing in Chrome (Version 60.0.3112.101 ) but a string in Firefox (54.0).

```
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data[0].title);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

note that if "alert" is used in  Chrome instead of "console.log" it works fine. Is there any way to make it work in Chrome?

thanks for any help.

Comment: [It works just fine in Chrome](https://jsfiddle.net/cek2yhyk/). If you really mean the *console*, remember that the console shows you the result of the last evaluated expression (in addition to any `console.log`s issued during the evaluation). I can't see why the above would result in `undefined`, but the code certainly doesn't `console.log` `undefined`.

Comment: and in fact if I add axios to this page, then run that code in Chrome's console, I only see `undefined` in the **unsettled** promise display, which isn't relevant (since the promise is unresolved).

Answer (score 2):

If I add axios to this page (here on SO), then run that code in Chrome's console, I see this in Chrome:

[image]

If you're referring to the `undefined` in `, [[PromiseValue]]: undefined`, ignore it. That's just the display of the Promise object returned by `catch`, which isn't settled yet (thus has no fulfillment value or rejection reason). That has nothing to do with the ultimate settlement of the promise, which as you can see at the bottom of that picture, is the string with the first title.

Comment: Looking at your  screen shot helped me solve my problem and it was a stupid noob error. My filters were on "hide all".  :-(

Comment: @Enirdas: Ack! Well, I'm glad the above helped. :-) If you like, unaccept the answer and I'll delete it, which will let you delete the question (you can delete a question if it has only one answer if the answer isn't upvoted). Entirely up to you. Happy coding!